# Recursion process

Tags: c, recursion

My questions is regarding recursion, and i am little stuck to understand one point. I debugged a small piece of code, and i know how the flow is working , but question why and how? I will explain my doubt.

I know it might be a stupid one to ask , but clear me on this one.

**Check the code** -:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int n);
void add(int number);

int main()
{
    int number, result;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum(number);
}

void  sum(int num)
{
    if (num!=0) {
        sum(num - 1); //(2-1) (1-1)
        sum(num - 1); // (1-1) (2-1)
        add(num);
    }

}

void add(int number){
    int a = 5;
    int c = 0;
    c = a+number;

    printf("%d ",c);
}
```

When I give a user input of 2 , flow goes to `if` condition -> Valiadte -> goes inside -> call first `sum` (2-1) -> goes up again -> validate -> call first `sum` (1-1) -> gets out of `if` -> calls second `sum` (1-1) -> goes out of `if` -> calls `add` function -> calls `sum` again now (2-1) -> validate `if` -> calls first `sum` (1-1) -> goes out -> call second `sum` again(1-1) -> calls `add` -> exit.

`Recursion` definition says -: When a function calls itself it's a recursive,The recursion continues until some condition is met to prevent it.

My question is why is second sum called 2 or more times?? I mean if you see it mets the condition `(1-1)` on first call, so it should exit out and just call add, but instead after calling `add` it again goes for `(2-1)`. Is the second `Sum` getting called in reverse order??

Is it like if first is called `123` then second have to go `321` even after it mets the condition ??Is that how recursion process actually works? Can anyone explain the concept?

---

A little update to my question. I removed second inner function call , and now left with one inner recursive function. Check updated code -:

```
void sum(int num)
{

    if (num != 0) {
        sum(num - 1);
    }

    if (num==2) {
        printf("Back to memory address of 2 , you can exit out of function now ");
    }

}
```

`Input = sum(2)`. Now when `sum` goes`sum(1-1)` or `sum(0)` -> exit if . I see the call didn't end out of function . The value of `num` is again traversed back to `2` going`(0->1>2)` -> goes inside `if (num==2)` -> print on console -> exit function.

What does that indicates ? If i make a guess is it like -: The inner call works as `pass by value` and not `reference`? So even inner recursive function is updating value of `num` it is not changing value at that `memory address` which is still `2` .

So is the flow something like this - :

`sum(2)` actual memory address value -> `sum(1)` copied value -> `sum(0)` copied value . Ok now I can go out of if .

But wait!! I am not able to go out of function , `num` have to go back and update with actual  memory address value -:

`num = 0 , num=1 , num=2(That's what I was looking for )` . Great!! out of function.

Is that what's happening ?? I am still little stuck.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do any recursion at all, it simply reads a number then quits. You call neither sum nor add from main.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Please use only the tag for the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir sorry let me update.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry sir will keep in mind.

Comment: The fact that it calls `sum` two times instead of once is just the way that recursive function is defined. You can indeed have multiple recursive calls in a recursive function. Nothing against it. It just accomplishes a different algorithm than if there's just one. This is quite common, in fact, for example in tree traversal functions: `traverse(node) { if (node == NULL) return; traverse(node->left); traverse(node-right); /* do something with current node */ }`.

Comment: @lurker I see that . Actually I was also trying merge sort where i saw such functionality. That really confused me out.

Comment: @lurker can you explain on updated question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some simple `printf` statements and keeping track of the "call depth" in a global `depth` variable provides a nice representation of what's going on:

```
int depth = 0;
void sum(int num)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) printf("\t");
    printf("-> sum | depth: %d | num: %d\n", depth, num);
    ++depth;

    if (num != 0) {
        sum(num - 1);
        sum(num - 1);
        add(num);
    }

    --depth;
}
```

With input `2`:

```
-> sum | depth: 0 | num: 2
    -> sum | depth: 1 | num: 1
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        add: 6
    -> sum | depth: 1 | num: 1
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        add: 6
    add: 7
```

You can also print at the end of `sum`, to see when the function is being exited:

```
-> sum | depth: 0 | num: 2
    -> sum | depth: 1 | num: 1
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        <- sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        <- sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        add: 6
    <- sum | depth: 1 | num: 1
    -> sum | depth: 1 | num: 1
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        <- sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        -> sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        <- sum | depth: 2 | num: 0
        add: 6
    <- sum | depth: 1 | num: 1
    add: 7
<- sum | depth: 0 | num: 2
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ryok4lNtF2TNiIqc)

Comment: thanks for this sir, but can you give me a theoretical idea of flow process ?? I mean my question ? Why it goes reverse order after setting condition instead exiting out? I don't understand from above solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "reverse order". What do you find unexpected by looking at the output above and carefully reading through the code?

Comment: oak sir, give me some time let me run and test it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I made a update. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you don't modify the value

```
void  sum(int num)
{
    if (num!=0) {
        sum(num - 1); //(2-1) (1-1) mark this as call [a]
        sum(num - 1); // (1-1) (2-1) mark this as call [b]
        add(num);
    }
}
```

When you call sum(2):

- the function call sum(1) at [a]
- and because 1 is not 0 it calls sum(0) at [a] again, recursively
- you do not modify number and this is why sum(0) at [b] is called again
- then is add(1) called,
- when it returns, you have just finished sum(1) at [a] call
- and now you call sum(1) at [b] because variable num is still 2 and it was not modified by the previous call
- and so on

Comment: is it because inner call is working as call by value and not reference?

Comment: and expression num - 1 does not edit value num itself

Comment: it's because each time a recursive function gets called , a memory block is placed on stack for that function, and when a condition is met it starts to pop out. That is why i see it going in reverse order. Thanks for your help for making it simpler.+1

Answer (score -1):

---

As you have it sum is never going to terminate (it would if you got rid of the second recursive 
call)
with an input of 2 the call sequence is:
call sum with 2
the if evaluates true so the first sum is called with argument of 1
the if is again true so the first sum is called now with argument of 0
the if evaluates false so now the second sum is called with argument of -1
the first if evaluates true so the first sum is called with argument of -2
the first if evaluates true so the first sum is called with -3..
.
I really do not understand why you have the second call to sum.

Comment: This does not seem a remotely accurate diagnosis to me.